# ember-cli-pagination - how to scroll to top of page on page change?

Tags: ember.js

I've got the `{{page-numbers}}` at the bottom of the page.  When I click a page number, the page loads fine, but I'm still at the bottom of the page.

How can I get it to scroll to the top when changing pages?

Is there a better addon to use for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to accomplish this by overriding the `page-numbers` component:

```
import PageNumberComponent from 'ember-cli-pagination/components/page-numbers';

export default PageNumberComponent.extend({
  actions: {
    pageClicked: function(number) {
      this._super(...arguments);
      window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
  }
});
```